# Problemas al exportar mapa web leaflet de Rstudio a HtTML

Tags: r, leaflet

Buen dia.

me encuentro desarrollando un mapa con R, en el cual se usan tres Shapfiles. En el mapa quiero asignar con icono dependiendo del valor de los atributos del shp.

Todo corre bien y se visualiza bien en el programa Rstudio, pero una vez se exporta este mapa a HTML los iconos no son visibles, y únicamente se ven los clouster de los puntos. Alguien tiene alguna idea.

El código implementado es el siguinete.

```
Actores<- st_read(dsn = "D:/PROYECTO CARTOGRAFIA SOCIAL/SHAPES PROYECTO", layer= "ACTORES84")
Colectivos<- st_read(dsn = "D:/PROYECTO CARTOGRAFIA SOCIAL/SHAPES PROYECTO", layer= "COLECTIVOS84")
Emociones <- st_read(dsn = "D:/PROYECTO CARTOGRAFIA SOCIAL/SHAPES PROYECTO", layer= "EMOCIONES84")
rasterEmo <- raster("D:/PROYECTO CARTOGRAFIA SOCIAL/SHAPES PROYECTO/inter2.tif")

paleta <- colorFactor(c("blue", "orange", "green", "red", "gold", "deeppink", "brown1", "firebrick3"),
                      domain = unique(Actores$ART_SECTOR))

paleta2 <- colorFactor(c("blue", "orange", "deepskyblue2", "red", "darkgreen", "Yellow", "yellow4", "pink", "green", "darkgray"),
                       domain = unique(Emociones$EMOCION))

pal <- colorNumeric(c("red", "green", "blue"), values(rasterEmo),
                    na.color = "transparent")

oceanIcons <- iconList(
  tristeza = makeIcon("D:/PROYECTO CARTOGRAFIA SOCIAL/iconos/1.tristeza.svg"),
  ira = makeIcon("D:/PROYECTO CARTOGRAFIA SOCIAL/iconos/2.ira.svg"),
  sorpresa= makeIcon("D:/PROYECTO CARTOGRAFIA SOCIAL/iconos/3.sorpresa.svg", 18, 18),
  miedo= makeIcon("D:/PROYECTO CARTOGRAFIA SOCIAL/iconos/4.miedo.svg", 18, 18),
  asco= makeIcon("D:/PROYECTO CARTOGRAFIA SOCIAL/iconos/5.asco.svg", 18, 18),
  felicidad= makeIcon("D:/PROYECTO CARTOGRAFIA SOCIAL/iconos/6.felicidad.svg", 18, 18),
  diversion= makeIcon("D:/PROYECTO CARTOGRAFIA SOCIAL/iconos/7.diversion.svg", 18, 18),
  gratitud= makeIcon("D:/PROYECTO CARTOGRAFIA SOCIAL/iconos/8.gratitud.svg", 18, 18),
  esperanza= makeIcon("D:/PROYECTO CARTOGRAFIA SOCIAL/iconos/9.esperanza.svg", 18, 18),
  orgullo = makeIcon("D:/PROYECTO CARTOGRAFIA SOCIAL/iconos/10.orgullo.svg", 18, 18))

IconActores <- iconList(
  Artes_Electronicas = makeIcon("D:/PROYECTO CARTOGRAFIA SOCIAL/iconos/1arteselectronicas.svg", 18, 18),
  audiovisuales = makeIcon("D:/PROYECTO CARTOGRAFIA SOCIAL/iconos/2Audiovisuales.svg", 18, 18),
  Literatura= makeIcon("D:/PROYECTO CARTOGRAFIA SOCIAL/iconos/3literatura.svg", 18, 18),
  Musica= makeIcon("D:/PROYECTO CARTOGRAFIA SOCIAL/iconos/4musica.svg", 18, 18),
  Danza= makeIcon("D:/PROYECTO CARTOGRAFIA SOCIAL/iconos/5danza.svg", 18, 18),
  intradisiplinar= makeIcon("D:/PROYECTO CARTOGRAFIA SOCIAL/iconos/6intradisiplinar.svg", 18, 18),
  Arte_Dramatico= makeIcon("D:/PROYECTO CARTOGRAFIA SOCIAL/iconos/7artedramatico.svg", 18, 18),
  Artes_Plasticas= makeIcon("D:/PROYECTO CARTOGRAFIA SOCIAL/iconos/8artesplasticas.svg", 18, 18))


l<- leaflet() %>% setView(-74.1646,4.5675,12)

l  %>%
  addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap",group = "OpenStreetMap") %>%
  addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldStreetMap",group = "Esri.WorldStreetMap") %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron",group = "CartoDB.Positron") %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.DarkMatter",group = "CartoDB.DarkMatter") %>%
  addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldImagery",group = "Esri.WorldImagery") %>%
  
  addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("OpenStreetMap", "Esri.WorldStreetMap", "CartoDB.DarkMatter","CartoDB.Positron", "Esri.WorldImagery"), position = "topright",
                   overlayGroups = c('Actores','Colectivos','Emociones','Analisis Emociones'),
                   options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = TRUE)) %>%
  
  addMiniMap(tiles = "OpenStreetMap", toggleDisplay = TRUE,
             position = "bottomleft", strings = list(hideText="Ocultar Minimapa", showText= "Mostrar Minimapa")) %>%
  htmlwidgets::onRender("
    function(el, x) {
      var myMap = this;
      myMap.on('baselayerchange',
        function (e) {
          myMap.minimap.changeLayer(L.tileLayer.provider(e.name));
        })
    }")%>%
  
  addTiles(group = "Actores")%>%
  addMarkers(data = Actores ,icon = ~IconActores[as.numeric(Actores$ART_SECTOR)], lat = Actores$LATITUD, lng = Actores$LONGITUD, group = "Actores", 
             popup = paste("<br>Nombres: ", Actores$NOMBRES,
                           "</br>Primer Apellido:", Actores$PRIMER_APE,
                           "</br>Segundo Apellido:", Actores$SEGUNDO_AP,
                           "</br>Identificacion:", Actores$DOC_NUM,
                           "</br>Sector:", Actores$SECTOR,
                           "</br>Roles:", Actores$ART_ROL,
                           "</br>Areas:", Actores$ART_AREA, sep = " "),
             label = Actores$SECTOR,
             clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(),
             clusterId = "ClousterActor")%>%
 
  
  addTiles(group = "Colectivos")%>%
  addMarkers(data = Colectivos, icon = list(iconUrl= "D:/PROYECTO CARTOGRAFIA SOCIAL/iconos/Colectivo.svg", iconSize = c(18, 18)),
             lat = Colectivos$LATITUD, lng = Colectivos$LONGITUD, group = "Colectivos", 
             popup = paste("<br>Nombre Colectivo: ",Colectivos$COL_NOM,
                           "</br>Numero de Miembros:", Colectivos$COL_NMIE,
                           "</br>Numero de Mujeres:", Colectivos$COL_NMUJ,
                           "</br>Años de Trabajo:", Colectivos$COL_AÑOS, sep = " "),
             label = Colectivos$COL_NOM,
             clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(),
             clusterId = "ClousterColectivos")%>%
 

  addTiles(group = "Emociones")%>%
  addMarkers(data = Emociones ,icon =  ~oceanIcons[Emociones$EMOCION],lat = Emociones$LATITUD, lng = Emociones$LONGITUD, group = "Emociones", 
             popup = paste( "<br>Emocion: ", Emociones$SENTIDO, sep = " "),
             label = Emociones$SENTIDO, clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(),
             clusterId = "ClousterEmociones")%>%
  
  #addHeatmap(lng = Emociones$LONGITUD, lat = Emociones$LATITUD, intensity = Emociones$EMOCION, radius = 15 )%>%
  
  
  #addTiles(group = 'Analisis Emociones') %>%
  #addRasterImage(rasterEmo, opacity = 0.8, group = "Analisis Emociones") %>%
  #addLegend(pal = pal,  position = "bottomright",values = values(rasterEmo),
  #title = "Emociones")%>%
  
  
  
addEasyButton(easyButton(
  states = list(
    easyButtonState(
      stateName="unfrozen-markers",
      icon="ion-toggle",
      title="Desactivar Clouster Actores",
      onClick = JS("
          function(btn, map) {
            var clusterManager =
              map.layerManager.getLayer('cluster', 'ClousterActor');
            clusterManager.freezeAtZoom();
            btn.state('frozen-markers');
          }")
    ),
    easyButtonState(
      stateName="frozen-markers",
      icon="ion-toggle-filled",
      title="Activar Clouster Actores",
      onClick = JS("
          function(btn, map) {
            var clusterManager =
              map.layerManager.getLayer('cluster', 'ClousterActor');
            clusterManager.unfreeze();
            btn.state('unfrozen-markers');
          }")
    )
  )
))%>%
  
  addEasyButton(easyButton(
    states = list(
      easyButtonState(
        stateName="unfrozen-markers",
        icon="ion-toggle",
        title="Desacctivar Clouster Emociones",
        onClick = JS("
          function(btn, map) {
            var clusterManager =
              map.layerManager.getLayer('cluster', 'ClousterEmociones');
            clusterManager.freezeAtZoom();
            btn.state('frozen-markers');
          }")
      ),
      easyButtonState(
        stateName="frozen-markers",
        icon="ion-toggle-filled",
        title="Activar Clouster Emociones",
        onClick = JS("
          function(btn, map) {
            var clusterManager =
              map.layerManager.getLayer('cluster', 'ClousterEmociones');
            clusterManager.unfreeze();
            btn.state('unfrozen-markers');
          }")
      )
    )
  ))%>%
  
  addEasyButton(easyButton(
    icon="fa-globe", title="Vista Ampliada",
    onClick=JS("function(btn, map){ map.setZoom(1); }"))) %>%
  addEasyButton(easyButton(
    icon="fa-crosshairs", title="Mi Ubicacion",
    onClick=JS("function(btn, map){ map.locate({setView: true}); }")))%>%
  
  
  #addStyleEditor()%>%
  
  addMeasure(
    position = "bottomright",
    primaryLengthUnit = "meters",
    primaryAreaUnit = "sqmeters",
    activeColor = "#3D535D",
    completedColor = "#7D4479",
    localization = "es")
```

[Esta imagen muestra la visualizacion en R studio, donde se ven los iconos generado. Los cuales se ven con normalidad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VxOy.jpg)

[Esta imagen muestra el mapa en HTML en google Crome, donde se puede ver que  los iconos desaparecen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDAI3.jpg)

No se a que de sebe el error, pero creo que se debe al comando "makeIcon", aunque no tengo sustento de ello.

agradezco cualquier comentario.
muchas gracias